# Using delegate decompiler and comparison in computed properties

Tags: entity-framework, properties, delegates, decompiler

I`m using delegate decompiler in my project.
https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler

Entity Model (part):

```
public long Id { get; set; }

public long ItemId { get; set; }

public long InfoItemId { get; set; }

[Computed]
public bool IsInfo
{
    get
    {
        return (InfoItemId > 0 && ItemId == 0) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

AttachmentModel:

```
private class AttachmentModel
{
    public string OriginalFileName { get; set; } 
    public string ItemFileType { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public bool IsInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Query (part):

```
Attachments = (from attachments in db.Attachments
                                        where attachments.ItemId == i.Id || attachments.InfoItemId == infoId
                                        select new AttachmentModel
                                        {
                                            OriginalFileName = attachments.ItemOriginalFileName,
                                            ItemFileType = attachments.ItemFileType,
                                            Thumbnail = attachments.FileThumbnailRelative,
                                            File = attachments.FileUrlRelative,
                                            Category = attachments.ItemFileCategory,
                                            IsInfo = attachments.IsInfo.Computed()
                                        }).ToList()
```

But I got an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   ComputedBoolean' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Q: It is possible use delegate decompiler in this case? How?
Please provide some example.

Comment: Hello, maybe it will be useful. I found the extremely useful Dave Glick [post] (https://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework) which describe different solutions. In my case, the Attachments used as the subquery, so when I use and move ".Decompile" method from the subquery to the top query level - it solved the problem for me.